# WORDLE - Read .txt file but if a word repeats dont use it again

Tags: c, file

im doing a simple Wordle clone in C. I already finished it but im adding some little things that i think make it nicer and that let me practice more since im still new to programming.

Anyways, the problem is, i use a .txt file to get the "random" words to guess, and the program allows you to play up to 8consecutive games to add up all your points and get a higher highscore. Therefore, there's a SLIGHT chance you can get the same word twice(or more) in the same run. **How can i make it so once a word is read in the .txt it gets *crossed out* and isnt take in consideration anymore**.. i thought of deleting it from the .txt but there's two problems with that. First, i dont want it to be removed for ever and have to keep writing it again into the file, and secondly my teacher said its not needed to do something so complicated for a necessity this simple... so yeah

**TL;DR:** How can i read random words in a .txt file and cross out the ones used, WHITOUT DELETING THEM or altering the file so it keeps the same for next games?

Here's the function i use to get the random words, what should i add?

```
void randomPalabra(char palabra[]) {

int lineaActual = 0, lineaElegida = 0;
bool seguirLeyendo = true;

srand(time(NULL));
lineaElegida = rand() % 30 + 1;


FILE* archivoTxt;

archivoTxt = fopen("palabras.txt", "r");
if (archivoTxt == NULL) {

    printf("El archivo no existe.");
}
else {

    do {

        fgets(palabra, 6, archivoTxt);

        if (_stricmp(palabra, "\n") != 0) {

            lineaActual++;
        }



    } while (lineaActual != lineaElegida); //Porque si hago esto funciona y se para pero si pongo un if(fgets..etc == NULL) no?? no son tecnicamente lo mismo escrito diferente?
    //por cierto, no entiendo porque de la nada fgets toma la string de caracteres y el \n como dos lineas diferentes, me vino de 10, pero antes no m funcionaba asi, y me tomaba siempre la palabra con el simbolo al final, por ejemplo "gatos\n". 

}

fclose(archivoTxt);
```

}

Comment: You would use another text file something like "usedwords.txt" read the words from that file, and check if the current word chosen exists in "usedwords.txt". If it exists, pick another word.

Comment: @Irelia That would make a good answer.

Comment: or you could simply have a table in memory of the (up to ) 8 words used so far. And if you happen to choose a duplicate word then just choose again

Comment: @pm100 how do you do that? would you mind puting it as an answer with code? i dont know how to have a table in memory

Comment: `"El archivo no existe."` is a terrible error message to write if the file exists but the user does not have permission to read it.  Don't guess why `fopen` fails, let the system tell you: `perror("palabras.txt");`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell hi william, its my first time ever importing a file and im really excited about it! i think i understand what you mean but how do i know what to printf?? i thought if =null then its just one possible reason and its because it does not exist! does this kind of info have a name or something so i can keep investigating about it? or is there a post explaining what error to show. thank u in advance

Comment: You print the system error message with `perror` or `strerror`.  eg `if( fopen(path, mode) == NULL ){ perror(path); ...}`. `fopen` sets the global variable `errno` when it fails, and `perror` uses `errno` to lookup the proper error message. Make sure you don't make any calls between `fopen` and `perror` that might change `errno`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a table in memory of the words used so far, since you specify a max of 8 its very simple.

this function returns true (1) if it remembered the word, false (0) if the word was already used

```
  int rememberWord(char* word) {
    static int used_word_count = 0;
    static char* used_words[8][6];

    for (int i = 0; i < used_word_count; i++) {
        if (strcmp(word, used_words[i]) == 0)
            return 0; // already used
    }

    strcpy(used_words[used_word_count],word);
    used_word_count++;
    return 1; // new word
}
```

hardcoded string length to be 6 (since wordle uses 5 character words)

so call this when you choose a word, if it returns zero it means you already used it

Comment: @OP I would of course sugest that you use c++, it is much easier to do this kind of thing using c++

Comment: i was actually thinking about this and trying to find the way to code it properly but i didnt know it was called table in memory !!! thank you so much for this and for letting me read the code so its easier, im grateful for it and im happy i was heading in the right direction!!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is implement a Map Abstract Data Type (ADT) (Key, Value) with a hashing algorithm. When you randomly select a word from `palabras.txt` you submit the word to your hashing algorithm giving you a key, place the word alongside your key in the ADT. When it's time to check if another chosen word has already been used, you simply run it through the hashing algorithm and quickly see if the newly selected word has already been placed into your ADT.

Here are some general prototypes of a Map ADT:

- put(key, value)
- get(key)
- contains_key(map, key)
- contains_value(map, value)
- remove(key)
- size()

Comment: Given that they were instructed not to do anything complicated, implementing a hash table, binary search tree or similar is quite a large overkill. Especially since all they really need to do is keep track of 8 words, and for every game they are re-reading the file. Using a map designed for fast searches is therefore pointless. Searching an array of words in memory is just fine. Or even just recording which word _indices_ were used is also fine. So the problem boils down to storing 8 numbers.

Comment: hey! as paddy said i dont really understand any of the concepts you stated but i do appreciate this answer because it seems as something i should learn sooner than later, so thank you! im adding topics to study once i think im capable enough and this ADT thing is definetly going to the list.